# How to add tags when uploading to S3 from pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, amazon-s3, tags

Pandas lets you pass an AWS S3 path directly to `.to_csv()` and `.to_parquet()`.
There's a `storage_options` argument for passing S3 specific arguments.

I would like to call `.to_csv('s3://bucket/key.csv', storage_options=something)` and specify S3 object tags to apply to the uploaded object, as `something`.
I've read the docs and I can't figure out how,

[The pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) don't list the possible values for `storage_options`, they just point to `fsspec`. It looks like pandas calls fsspec which calls s3fs which calls aiobotocore which calls botocore, and that probably calls s3transfer. How can I pass S3 tag arguments all the way down this rabbit hole?

## MWE

```
import pandas as pd
import boto3

bucket = 'mybucket' # change for your bucket
key = 'test/pandas/tags.csv'
tags = {'mytag': 'x'}

df = pd.DataFrame([{'a': 1}])
df.to_csv(f"s3://{bucket}/{key}") # try without any tags first
df.to_csv(f"s3://{bucket}/{key}", storage_options={'tags': tags})

resp = boto3.client('s3').get_object_tagging(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
actual_tags = {t['Key']: t['Value'] for t in resp.get('TagSet', [])}
assert actual_tags == tags
```

## expected behavior

Assertion passes. S3 object has tag `mytag`: `x`

## actual behavior

The second `.to_csv()` line fails.
i.e. it works without tags. The tags are what's causing failure.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "upld.py", line 9, in <module>
    df.to_csv(f"s3://{bucket}/{key}", storage_options={'tags': tags})
  File "/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.8.11/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3463, in to_csv
    return DataFrameRenderer(formatter).to_csv(
  File "/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.8.11/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py", line 1105, in to_csv
    csv_formatter.save()
  File "/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.8.11/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/csvs.py", line 237, in save
    with get_handle(
  File "/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.8.11/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 608, in get_handle
    ioargs = _get_filepath_or_buffer(
  File "/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.8.11/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 357, in _get_filepath_or_buffer
    file_obj = fsspec.open(
  File "/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.8.11/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fsspec/core.py", line 456, in open
    return open_files(
  File "/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.8.11/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fsspec/core.py", line 299, in open_files
    [fs.makedirs(parent, exist_ok=True) for parent in parents]
  File "/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.8.11/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fsspec/core.py", line 299, in <listcomp>
    [fs.makedirs(parent, exist_ok=True) for parent in parents]
  File "/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.8.11/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fsspec/asyn.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return sync(self.loop, func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.8.11/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fsspec/asyn.py", line 71, in sync
    raise return_result
  File "/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.8.11/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fsspec/asyn.py", line 25, in _runner
    result[0] = await coro
  File "/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.8.11/lib/python3.8/site-packages/s3fs/core.py", line 746, in _makedirs
    await self._mkdir(path, create_parents=True)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.8.11/lib/python3.8/site-packages/s3fs/core.py", line 731, in _mkdir
    await self._call_s3("create_bucket", **params)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.8.11/lib/python3.8/site-packages/s3fs/core.py", line 252, in _call_s3
    await self.set_session()
  File "/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.8.11/lib/python3.8/site-packages/s3fs/core.py", line 395, in set_session
    self.session = aiobotocore.session.AioSession(**self.kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'tags'
```

It looks like these arguments are being passed to the aiobotocore session instantiation, not the actual S3 put_object API call from aiobotocore. That makes me think it is not possible to do this.

## Alternatives

Should I try:

```
storage_options={
    'tags': {
        'k': 'v'
    }
}
```

or

```
storage_options={
    'tags': [
        {'Key': 'k', 'Value': 'v'}
    ]
}
```

Of course I could upload without tags, then add tags as a separate boto call.
This is not atomic, and costs twice as much (for small files.)
If there was a way to get the version id back from the upload, that would eliminate some concurrency issues (concurrent writes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I spent some time digging around in this. I could be wrong here, but I do not think it is possible. Here is why I believe that:

`storage_options` gets passed along to `fsspec` if the path is a url not beginning with `http` ([see here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/ba2fdb14fadd09f03863681d1df1fffa4ba13f9a/pandas/io/common.py#L244)). Then these options are passed through `fsspec` to `s3fs.S3Filesystem` as `kwargs`. Then the kwargs dead-end with the function in your error message.

(this is where I could be wrong!) Then the `S3FileSystem` does a `_put_file` call to write your csv. This function does not use `self.kwargs`, but takes in function-level `kwargs` that will not be passed by pandas.

Thus, I do not think tags are accessible through `to_X` in pandas. However, it would be worthwhile to raise an issue on Pandas/fsspec github to get more info.